# How to call HTML page as a popup from another HTML page using Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-views

I am working on Django project where i need pop up the HTML when i click the button. Let me explain, when ever user click the button it should open another HTML as a popup there user can upload the files and download the sample files. Could you please help me on the issue

Here is my code below,

HTML Button -

```
<button data-href='{% url "employeeBulkUpload" companydetail.id %}' id="uploadEmployees" title="Upload Employees" class="btn btn-blue mr-2 px-3 d-block w-100 text-95 radius-round border-2 brc-black-tp10"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></button>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#uploadEmployees').initDialog({'url': '{% url "employeeBulkUpload" companydetail.id %}', 'title': 'Upload Employees'}); });
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to use modal for this purpose, you can write your form in a html modal element and render it on button click

Answer (score 1):

You need to use modal to achieve your task. You can get more info about html modals on this [link for jquery modals](https://jquerymodal.com/).